# How can I lazy load icons from Vue CoreUI?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, core-ui

I just ran npm run build on my vue 3 project and my vendor.js file turns out to be 10MB!!!

And when I briefly scan the code of that file, it seems to be mostly filled with svg code. So I'm assuming that that's all the icons from coreui. Because currently, my `main.ts` file has this code:

```
import { CIcon } from '@coreui/icons-vue'
import * as coreuiIcons from '@coreui/icons'
app.provide('icons', coreuiIcons)
app.component('CIcon', CIcon)
```

So I'm wondering if it's possible to let those icons load lazily, just whenever they're being called for in the templates.

So far, I've tried it like this:

```
// CIconWrapper.vue

<template>
  <CIcon :icon="i" :size="size" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { CIcon } from "@coreui/icons-vue"

const { icon, size = "" } = defineProps<{ icon: string, size?: string }>()
const i = await import('@coreui/icons')[icon]
</script>
```

And then as fas as a I know, asynchronous Vue components only really work when wrapping them inside a Suspense, so I created another wrapper for the wrapper:

```
// CIconWrapperSuspense.vue

<template>
  <Suspense>
     <template #default>
       <CIcon :icon="icon" :size="size" />
     </template>
     <template #fallback>
       Loading...
     </template>
  </Suspense>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { Suspense } from "vue"
import { default as CIcon } from "./CIconWrapper.vue"

const { icon, size = "" } = defineProps<{ icon: string, size?: string }>()
</script>
```

And then I changed my code in `main.ts` to look like this:

```
import { default as CIcon } from '@/components/CIconWrapperSuspense.vue'
app.component('CIcon', CIcon)
```

But it doesn't do *anything*. Like literally nothing. No loading screen even.

So if you have any tips on how to make this actually work, I would be incredibly grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed it! :-D

So I threw away `CIconWrapperSuspense.vue`, that wasn't necessary at all.
Then I rewrote `CIconWrapper.vue` as follows:

```
<template>
  <CIcon v-if="i" :content="i" :size="size" :customClasses="customClasses" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue"
import { CIcon } from "@coreui/icons-vue"

let i = $ref()
const { icon, size = "", customClasses = "" } = defineProps<{
  icon: string, size?: string, customClasses?: string|string[]|object
}>()

onMounted(async () => {
  const iconName = icon.replace(/-(\w)/g, match => match[1].toUpperCase())
  const fileName = icon.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, match => `${match[0]}-${match[1].toLowerCase()}`)
  // Vite / Rollup only accept dynamic imports that start with ./ or ../
  i = (await import(`../../node_modules/@coreui/icons/js/free/${fileName}.js`))[iconName]
})
</script>
```

And now my `main.ts` file has this code:

```
// icons
import CIcon from '@/components/CIconWrapper.vue'
app.component('CIcon', CIcon)
```